# problem with a polynomial integral i can't solve

Tags: calculus, integration

i'm having problem with solving this integral: $\int \frac{2x-\sqrt{4x^2-x+1}}{x-1}dx$.

i am getting that the term inside the square root is complex, and i don't know how to solve it.

I've tried also to multiply the fraction by (x-1) or (x+y), but still no result.

could you please help me with it?

Comment: Is there a sign after $2x-1$

Comment: Do you mean $(2x-1)\sqrt{\cdots}$?

Comment: sorry, without -1. fixed it

Comment: you could split it up into two bits, then the square root part, substitute the x-1 away with u = x-1, then complete the square inside the square root, then you could use a substitution possibly based in sinh, so you'd get a cosh^2 / sinh^2 is (1 - sinh^2) / sinh = csch - sinh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is a shorter way to do this integral, but I think this will work. First make the following change of variables $t=\sqrt{4x^2-x+1}-2x$. This implies:

$$\sqrt{4x^2-x+1}=2x+t \;\;\Longrightarrow\;\;4x^2-x+1=(2x+t)^2 \;\;\Longrightarrow\;\; x=\frac{1-t^2}{4t+1}\,.$$

Differentiating we get:

$$ dx = -\frac{4t^2+2t+4}{(4t+1)^2}dt\,.$$

Replacing in the integral one gets:

$$I=\int\frac{2x-\sqrt{4x^2-x+1}}{x-1}dx=\int\frac{t}{(1-t^2)/(4t+1)-1}\cdot\frac{4t^2+2t+4}{(4t+1)^2}dt\,,$$

which is a rational integral, and therefore doable. After some minor algebra:

$$\begin{align}I &=-\int\frac{4t^2+2t+4}{(4t+1)(t+4)}dt\\
&=-\int\frac{4t^2+2t+4}{4t^2+17t+4}dt\\
&=-\int\left(1-\frac{15t}{4t^2+17t+4}\right)dt\\
&=-t+\int\frac{15t}{(4t+1)(t+4)}dt\,.
\end{align}$$

The fraction in this last integral can we written as:

$$\frac{15t}{(4t+1)(t+4)} = \frac{4}{t+4}-\frac{1}{4t+1}\,,$$

so

$$I=-t+\int\frac{4}{t+4}dt-\int\frac{1}{4t+1}dt=-t+4\ln(t+4)-\frac{1}{4}\ln(4t+1)+C\,,$$

where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. Reverting to the initial variable ($x$) gives:

$$\begin{align}I\;=\;&2x-\sqrt{4x^2-x+1}+4\ln(\sqrt{4x^2-x+1}-2x+4)\\
&-\frac{1}{4}\ln(4\sqrt{4x^2-x+1}-8x+1)+C\,.
\end{align}$$